# How to change the label in form immediately using vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public Sub login()
    frmLogin.lblMsg = "Logging in..."
    MsgBox "Login successfully"
End Sub
```

When I call this Sub, I want to change the label to "Logging in..." during process, but it does not work. The label just change when the Sub was complete (after message box show the message). Is the form runs on one thread? Is any way to solve this?

Comment: `frmLogin.lblMsg.caption` and `frmLogin.repaint`

Comment: Actually you can do it only with `frmLogin.Repaint`, the `frmLogin.lblMsg.caption` is not needed.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks, it works.

Comment: @Vityata Exactly, thank you bro